# Good example for tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Where can I find a good example for TabHost? I've found lots of examples but all of them are deprecated or don't work.

Comment: The examples that use TabActivity will be deprecated because  TabActivity itself is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They now want you to use Fragments with tabs, and no longer Activities. Probably this is because of performance reasons.

[This example](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) does not look bad while it is more complex that minimally required. You need to rip away two thirds of the code before you can build your own on the top of that remains. Otherwise, it works well enough to be recommended.

Comment: @Audrius Meškauskas Could you explain me why do you put inside `FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"` two elements while in documentation `FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html